# Grep for part of a line and replace

Tags: bash, scripting, grep

New to Bash, using grep etc. and finding it confusing. Say I have a file that looks like this:

```
ABC: first example [1.0] ----
ABC: second example [1.1] ----
DEF: third example [1.2] ----
DEF: fourth example [1.3] ----
```

How could I use grep to get all lines that start with ABC, end with the word example, and cut out everything in the line after example?

Desired output

```
ABC: first example
ABC: second example
```

Comment: You wouldn't. grep is not an editor, it's simply to find strings that match regexps (`g/re/p` = `Globally find a Regular Expression and Print the result`) it's not meant for modifying anything. To modify text you should use sed or awk. While the GNU guys have for reasons beyond mortal ken been trying to change grep into a Swiss army knife, ignore all of that and just use grep as originally intended. We already have other UNIX tools for the rest. See [@dawg's answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/43309178/1745001).

Answer (score 5):

Given:

```
$ echo "$txt"
ABC: first example [1.0] ----
ABC: second example [1.1] ----
DEF: third example [1.2] ----
DEF: fourth example [1.3] ----
```

You can use `sed`:

```
$ echo "$txt" | sed -n 's/\(^ABC.*example\).*$/\1/p'
ABC: first example
ABC: second example
```

If your content is in a file, you would do:

```
$ sed -n 's/\(^ABC.*example\).*$/\1/p' file
```

Explanation:

```
sed -n 's/\(^ABC.*example\).*$/\1/p'
     ^                                 don't print unless p directive
        ^                              substitute 
           ^              ^            capture group -- parens need to be escaped
             ^                         ABC at start of line
                ^                      anything up to example
                           ^           everything after example to end of line
                              ^        replace entire line with capture group
                                  ^    p means print that if sub made
```

Or, you can use `awk`:

```
$ echo "$txt" | awk 'match($0, /^ABC.* example/){print substr($0, RSTART, RLENGTH)}'
ABC: first example
ABC: second example
```

---

If you want to use [word boundaries](http://www.regular-expressions.info/refwordboundaries.html) (so that *example* is different than *examples* or *nonexample* and *example is only matched as a standalone word) you can do:

```
$ echo "$txt" | sed -n -E 's/(^ABC.*[[:<:]]example[[:>:]]).*$/\1/p'
```

Or, with `gawg`:

```
$ echo "$txt" | gawk 'match($0, /^ABC.*\<example\>/){print substr($0, RSTART, RLENGTH)}'
```

Answer (score 3):

With GNU `grep`:

```
grep -o '^ABC.*\<example\>'
```

- `-o` gets only the matched portion
- `^ABC` matches `ABC` at the start of the line
- `.*` greedily matches everything upto `example`, `\<` matches zero-width word boundary before `example`, similarly `\>` matches word boundary after `example`

Note that, this matches lines starting with `ABC` and has `example`, not necessarily last word as `example`. In the latter case, and if you meant to match only alphabetics (character class `[:alpha:]`) as word constituent characters, leverage PCRE (`-P`) if your `grep` supports this (e.g. GNU `grep`) and use zero-width positive lookahead:

```
grep -Po '^ABC.*\bexample\b(?=[^[:alpha:]]*$)'
```

**Example:**

```
% cat file.txt 
ABC: first example [1.0] ----
ABC: second example [1.1] ----
DEF: third example [1.2] ----
DEF: fourth example [1.3] ----

% grep -o '^ABC.*\<example\>' file.txt
ABC: first example
ABC: second example

% grep -Po '^ABC.*\bexample\b(?=[^[:alpha:]]*$)' file.txt
ABC: first example
ABC: second example
```

Comment: You should mention that's GNU-specific and the `-P` is highly experimental so YMMV.

Comment: The word boundary assertions `\<` are GNU specific. POSIX would be `[[:<:]]` if supported.

Comment: Additionally, `-o` itself is a GNU extension. See [the POSIX grep spec](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/grep.html)